# It is satisfactory when... I feel satisfaction when

Tags: expressions, formulation-idiomatique

Je cherche une expression qui exprime le sens de *it is satisfactory when...* ou *I feel satisfaction when...* ou même *I find satisfaction in...*

J'ai essayé de formuler ces expressions mais je ne suis pas sûr de leur exactitude:

> Il est plaisant quand...
>
> Je sens satisfaction quand... ou Je me sens satisfait quand...
>
> Je trouve satisfaction en/à...

Est-ce que vous pourriez m'aider, s'il vous plaît?

Comment: If you don't mind changing the order (and voice) of your phrases, you could consider using "... me donne (de la) satisfaction. (Quand je vois que  les gens apprecient mon boulot, ca/cela me donne (de la) satisfaction)

Comment: @PapaPoule bien sûr que oui! ça me plaît aussi. Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

### Oui

> Je ressens de la satisfaction à…
>   Je trouve satisfaction à…
>   Je tire ma satisfaction de…

### Bof

> Il est plaisant quand…
>   Je me sens satisfait quand…

### Comment choisir

Cela dépend du contexte, de ce qui est à exprimer et de comment l'exprimer, mais il est difficile de donner une règle complète, d'autant que les nuances entre les différentes propositions sont minimes.

## Long

La traduction est parfois un art difficile. Les propositions de la question sont syntaxiquement correctes (hormis « Je sens satisfaction quand… » que j'écrirais plutôt « Je ressens de la satisfaction à… »).

### Ce qui ne convient pas vraiment

« Plaisant » exprime mal *satisfactory*. Bien que le sentiment résultant de la satisfaction soit analogue, « plaisant » est associé à un bonheur ne dépendant pas forcément de soi-même alors que l'on tire généralement sa satisfaction de ses propres actions et de leurs conséquences.

> Il est plaisant de travailler au sein d'une équipe avec une si bonne ambiance.

Bien que correct, « je me sens satisfait quand… » semble un peu plus lourd, un peu moins naturel.

> Je me sens satisfait quand je sais que les utilisateurs aiment mon logiciel.

### Ce qui convient

Les autres propositions me paraissent correctes, moyennant la correction suggérée plus haut :

> Je ressens de la satisfaction à fournir un travail de qualité.
>   Je trouve satisfaction à écrire du code sans bug.

« Je trouve satisfaction » est correct mais je pense qu'il implique une tournure peut-être un peu littéraire qui n'est peut-être pas évidente à utiliser partout.

J'ajouterais comme possibilité « Je tire ma satisfaction de… ».

> Je tire ma satisfaction des retours que me font les clients.

Comment: Merci mille fois. Mais j'ai encore une question. Selon Wiktionnaire, *tirer satisfaction* signifie *faire réparer une injure, une offense*. Pourriez vous expliquer pourquoi on utilise ça expression ici? Et pourquoi *je me sens **satisfait*** ce n'est pas naturel quand on peut dire *je me sens bien* pour exprimer, dans une certain mesure, la même chose que je trouve traduire?

Comment: @NicholasJ. Concernant « tirer satisfaction », [la définition du Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer_satisfaction) me paraît désuette (la référence date de 1935). Cela m'évoque un duel pour régler un différent. Ici, on parle de « tirer satisfaction » comme on parlerait de « tirer du plaisir » : c'est le sentiment que l'on retire d'une action. Concernant « je me sens satisfait », c'est lourd. On choisira communément une forme plus légère comme « je suis satisfait ». À l'oral, il est d'ailleurs de plus en plus courant d'entendre « je suis bien » pour « je me sens bien ».

Comment: Merci, monsieur. Votre réponses m'aident beaucoup toujours!